# install package socket.io-client-swift xcode 12

Tags: ios, macos, xcode12, carthage

I need to install with carthage the package https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift
with a Xcode 12 project.

i have a CartFile :

```
github "socketio/socket.io-client-swift" ~> 15.0.0
```

I have tried this command :

```
carthage update --platform iOS --use-xcframeworks
```

I try :

- modify the "Buid archicture only" on "NO" in my main project
- modify the "Buid archicture only" on "NO" in the dependency "Starscream" project

but always i have the same error :

```
CompileSwift normal i386 (in target 'SocketIO' from project 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift')
    cd /Users/admin/Documents/test2/Carthage/Checkouts/socket.io-client-swift
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/admin/Documents/test2/Carthage/Checkouts/socket.io-client-swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swi$
/Users/admin/Documents/test2/Carthage/Checkouts/socket.io-client-swift/Source/SocketIO/Engine/SocketEngine.swift:27:8: error: could not find module 'Starscream' for target 'i386-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, armv7-$
import Starscream
```

Maybe i need to create a ${ARCHS_STANDARD} in some env or/and custom file ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that Carthage doesn't set the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` correctly in many cases, which for me caused Socket.IO to be unable to find Starscream when compiling.

Here's a workaround script you can use to set the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`:

```sh
# carthage.sh
# Usage example: ./carthage.sh build --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS

set -euo pipefail

xcconfig=$(mktemp /tmp/static.xcconfig.XXXXXX)
trap 'rm -f "$xcconfig"' INT TERM HUP EXIT

echo "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=\$(inherited) $(pwd)/Carthage/Build" >> $xcconfig
# echo 'BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES' >> $xcconfig # You may or may not need this depending on your project setup

export XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="$xcconfig"
carthage "$@"
```